# Perl, find a match and read next line in perl

Tags: perl

I would like to use

```
myscript.pl targetfolder/*
```

to read some number from ASCII files.

#### myscript.pl

```
@list = <@ARGV>;

# Is the whole file or only 1st line is loaded?

foreach $file ( @list ) {
    open (F, $file);
}

# is this correct to judge if there is still file to load?

while ( <F> ) {
    match_replace()
}

sub match_replace {

    # if I want to read the 5th line in downward, how to do that?
    # if I would like to read multi lines in multi array[row],
    # how to do that?

    if ( /^\sName\s+/ ) {
        $name = $1;
    }               
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a thorough read of [`perlintro`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html) - it will give you a lot of the information you need. Additional comments:

1. Always use [`strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html). The first will enforce some good coding practices (like for example declaring variables), the second will inform you about potential mistakes. For example, one warning produced by the code you showed would be `readline() on unopened filehandle F`, giving you the hint that `F` is not open at that point (more on that below).
2. `@list = <@ARGV>;`: This is a bit tricky, I wouldn't recommend it - you're essentially using [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html), and expanding `targetfolder/*` is something your shell should be doing, and if you're on Windows, I'd recommend [`Win32::Autoglob`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Autoglob) instead of doing it manually.
3. `foreach ... { open ... }`: You're not doing anything with the files once you've opened them - the loop to read from the files needs to be inside the `foreach`.
4. *"Is the whole file or only 1st line  is loaded?"* [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) doesn't read anything from the file, it just opens it and provides a *filehandle* (which you've named `F`) that you then need to read from.
5. I'd strongly recommend you use the more modern three-argument form of `open` and check it for errors, as well as use lexical filehandles since their scope is not global, as in `open my $fh, '<', $file or die "$file: $!";`.
6. *"is this correct to judge if there is still file to load?"* Yes, `while (<$filehandle>)` is a good way to read a file line-by-line, and the loop will end when everything has been read from the file. You may want to use the more explicit form `while (my $line = <$filehandle>)`, so that your variable has a name, instead of the default [`$_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$_) variable - it does make the code a bit more verbose, but if you're just starting out that may be a good thing.
7. `match_replace()`: You're not passing any parameters to the `sub`. Even though this code might still "work", it's passing the current line to the `sub` through the global `$_` variable, which is not a good practice because it will be confusing and error-prone once the script starts getting longer.
8. `if (/^\sName\s+/){$name = $1;}`: Since you've named the `sub` `match_replace`, I'm guessing you want to do a search-and-replace operation. In Perl, that's called `s/search/replacement/`, and you can read about it in [`perlrequick`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html) and [`perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html). As for the code you've shown, you're using `$1`, but you don't have any "capture groups" (`(...)`) in your regular expression - you can read about that in those two links as well.
9. *"if I want to read the 5th line in downward , how to do that ?"* As always in Perl, There Is More Than One Way To Do It (TIMTOWTDI). One way is with the [range operator `..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) - you can skip the first through fourth lines by saying `next if 1..4;` at the beginning of the while loop, this will test those line numbers against the special [`$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$.) variable that keeps track of the most recently read line number.
10. *"and if I would like to read multi lines in multi array[row], how to do that ?"* One way is to use [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) to add the current line to the end of an array. Since keeping the lines of a file in an array can use up more memory, especially with large files, I'd strongly recommend making sure you think through the algorithm you want to use here. You haven't explained *why* you would want to keep things in an array, so I can't be more specific here.

So, having said all that, here's how I might have written that code. I've added some debugging code using [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) - it's always helpful to see the data that your script is working with.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper; # for debugging
$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1;

for my $file (@ARGV) {
    print Dumper($file);  # debug
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "$file: $!";
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        next if 1..4;
        chomp($line);  # remove line ending
        match_replace($line);
    }
    close $fh;
}

sub match_replace {
    my ($line) = @_;  # get argument(s) to sub
    my $name;
    if ( $line =~ /^\sName\s+(.*)$/ ) {
        $name = $1;
    }
    print Data::Dumper->Dump([$line,$name],['line','name']);  # debug
    # ... do more here ...
}
```

The above code is explicitly looping over [`@ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@ARGV) and opening each file, and I did say above that more verbose code can be helpful in understanding what's going on. I just wanted to point out a nice feature of Perl, the "magic" `<>` operator (discussed in [`perlop` under "I/O Operators"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators)), which will automatically open the files in `@ARGV` and read lines from them. (There's just one small thing, if I want to use the `$.` variable and have it count the lines per file, I need to use the `continue` block I've shown below, this is explained in [`eof`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html).) This would be a more "idiomatic" way of writing that first loop:

```
while (<>) {  # reads line into $_
    next if 1..4;
    chomp;    # automatically uses $_ variable
    match_replace($_);
} continue { close ARGV if eof }  # needed for $. (and range operator)
```

Comment: @Borodin I prefer TIMTOWTDI over TMTOWTDI, as in "T**i**m Toady". The two are basically equivalent so there's no need to "fix" it.

Comment: @haukex: As you wish. I have seen the alternative spelling creep in over the last twenty years, and assumed that it was a back-derivation from the phrase *tim-toady* where the author hadn't seen the acronym in print. But if you have a preference for the variation then you are just as welcome to use it you are to spell the language *Pearl*.

Comment: @Borodin So you're saying that using TIMTOWTDI instead of TMTOWTDI is on the same level as spelling the language "Pearl"? That's not very Perlish of you (and kind of ironic), since there *is* more than one way to do it 

Comment: @haukex: May I ask one more question ?  Acutally I would like to go thought every files in the main  and  then go thought every line of the open file in the subroutine.  Because I need to do multiple match_replace in same file thus I have multiple subroutines.
In that case , what variable I should pass from main to subroutine? 
I should do $line = <$fh>  in the main or in the subroutines ?

Comment: @seedof I'm a little unclear on what exactly you want to do with multiple matches, perhaps it would be best to explain (with code) in a new question. But in general: Yes, you can pass `$fh` around like a normal variable (because it is a normal variable), and if you want to do `<$fh>` in the `sub` that's fine too - but if you have multiple `sub`s, I would recommend against doing `<$fh>` in multiple places, that's something that will usually make code much more complicated than it needs to be.